# Host and Port to access the Kubernetes api

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I can access the kubernetes api to get the deployments using Kubernetes proxy.

I get the list of deployments with:

```
127.0.0.1:8001/apis/apps/v1/deployments
```

This is getting the deployments locally. But what should I use the `HOST` and `PORT` to access the deployments from the cluster not locally but using the aws server. 
I am new to Kubernetes, if the question is not understandable please let me know. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have used kops to setup your cluster, this answer also might be helpful: https://serverfault.com/a/918110/469845

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl proxy` forwards your traffic localy adding your authentication for you

Your public api endpoint can be exposed in different ways (or it can be completely inaccessible from public network) depending on your cluster setup.

In most cases it would be exposed on something like ie. https://api.my.cluster.fqdn or with custom port like https://api.my.cluster.fqdn:6443 and it would require authentication by ie. getting a baerer token or using client certificate. It is reasonable to use some client library to connect to API.